# Как получить значения переменно?

Tags: javascript

На странице сайта есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="config">
    window.__INIT_CONFIG__ = "data json...";
</script>
```

Мне через консоль браузера нужно обратиться к переменной **window.**INIT_CONFIG****

Это возможно? как?

Буду благодарен за пояснение!

Comment: так как написано так и обратиться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `console.log( window.__INIT_CONFIG__ ) ` выдает *undefined*

Comment: Нет, конкретно с этим кодом всё в порядке........если только вместо `"data json..."` там не стоИт переменная неинициализированная

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так

```js
window.__INIT_CONFIG__ = "data json...";

console.log(window.__INIT_CONFIG__);
console.log(window["__INIT_CONFIG__"]);

var name = "__INIT_CONFIG__";
console.log(window[name]);
```

но может и такое быть

```js
window.__INIT_CONFIG__ = "data json...";

console.log(window.__INIT_CONFIG__);
console.log(window["__INIT_CONFIG__"]);

//в глубинах может и такое случится
var a;

window.__INIT_CONFIG__ = a;

console.log(window.__INIT_CONFIG__);
console.log(window["__INIT_CONFIG__"]);
```